# multidimensional arrays of data frames

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, dataframe

I like to define an 3D-array of data.frame(A,B,C,...) so that I can do

```
for (x in 1:4)
  for (y in 1:5)
    for (z in 1:5) {
       m[x,y,z]$A <- dnorm(1)
       m[x,y,z]$B <- dnorm(1)
       m[x,y,z]$C <- dnorm(1)
    }
```

it would be ok too, if I get a data.frame(x,y,z,A,B,C) with x,y,z ids and a short and effizient way to manipulate and read any line "x,y,z".

Perhaps there are better ideas? I like to get rid of

```
mA[x,y,z] <- ...
mB[x,y,z] <- ...
mC[x,y,z] <- ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you meant `rnorm` since populating an entire array with `dnorm(1)` wouldn't seem very interesting. It would be a lot faster to make the arrays in one pass with:

```
m <- array( rnorm(4*5*5*3), 
            dims= c(4,5,5, 3) , 
            dimnames=list(x=NULL, y=NULL, z=NULL, lets=c("A","B","C") ) )
```

So access from that 4d array, it would be:

```
> m[ 1,1,1,"A"]
                 A 
0.6773062520076687 

> m[ 1,1,1,"B"]
                 B 
0.6229924684213618

> m[ 1,1,1,"C"]
                 C 
0.6899440670029088
```

Or if you wanted all three of them as a vector:

```
> m[ 1,1,1, ]
                 A                  B                  C 
0.6773062520076687 0.6229924684213618 0.6899440670029088
```

Answer (score 7):

A more standard format would be a data frame with 6 columns --- x, y, z, A, B, and C. You can achieve this with:

```
dat <- expand.grid(x=1:4, y=1:5, z=1:5, A=dnorm(1), B=dnorm(1), C=dnorm(1))
head(dat)
#   x y z         A         B         C
# 1 1 1 1 0.2419707 0.2419707 0.2419707
# 2 2 1 1 0.2419707 0.2419707 0.2419707
# 3 3 1 1 0.2419707 0.2419707 0.2419707
# 4 4 1 1 0.2419707 0.2419707 0.2419707
# 5 1 2 1 0.2419707 0.2419707 0.2419707
# 6 2 2 1 0.2419707 0.2419707 0.2419707
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the other two answers here are almost certainly what you want. But out of interest, you can make a 3-dimensional list of data.frames:

```
a <- data.frame(x = rnorm(2700), y = rnorm(2700), z = rnorm(2700))
b <- plyr::alply(expand.grid(A = 0:2, B = 0:2, C = 0:2), 1, function(x) with(x, a[9 * C + 3 * B + A + 1:100, ]))
dim(b) <- rep(3, 3)

b[[1, 2, 3]]$x
```

Comment: plus 1 for abusing `dim` like that.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers offer good alternatives to what you originally wanted to do. Use one of them.

But for the heck of it, here's one way to solve the original problem:

```
m_dims <- c(4, 5, 5)
make_data_frame <- function(i) {
  data.frame(A = dnorm(1), B = dnorm(2), C = dnorm(3))
}
m <- lapply(seq_len(prod(m_dims)), make_data_frame)
m <- array(m, m_dims)
```

Note that you need double brackets to access this beast:

```
m[[1, 1, 1]]$A
```

Playing around (and making mistakes) with this is a good way to get more familiar with how R implements lists, matrices, and data frames. But I can't say I'd recommend it.

Comment: @NickK I saw yours and almost backed out of posting mine. 1) I didn't think yours was crassly inefficient enough, and 2) I wanted to demonstrate how to turn a list into an array.

Comment: I'd actually forgotten you could use multiple indices in double brackets for multidimensional lists so I'm glad you posted yours. Not that I'd imagine I'll use a multidimensional list very often!